# Word for off-topic discussion

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word that simply means "off-topic discussion." Banter is close because it means playful remarks, which can possibly denote off-topic discussion, but not really. Is there a word for this?

"We need to stay focused on the topic at hand and avoid all of this _____."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tangent" is the word that comes to mind, although it doesn't fit into the blank you've left.

E.G.

"During the lecture on the civil war, Ms. Appleby went off on a *tangent* and told us all about the time her dad fell down the stairs."

"Although our discussion of peach farming was *tangent* to the given topic of crop rotation, it was still fruitful."

Comment: This works perfect actually, thanks. I just rephrased my statement.